# Cannot DELETE from mongodb in Express app

Tags: rest, express

I'm building a very simple app to practice RESTful routing using Express and Mongodb.

My problem is that, whenever I try to run the DELETE route, I get the following error: `Cannot DELETE /wordlist/59a7194293de6e03630401f6`

Here is the delete route:

```
app.delete("wordlist/:id", function(req, res){
  Word.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
    if(err){
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/wordlist");
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the form I'm using to run the delete route using ejs:

```
<form action="/wordlist/<%= word._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
  <button>
    Delete this word
  </button>
</form>
```

Also, I have installed and used method-override.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the route that you have specified:

`app.delete("wordlist/:id"...`

You are missing a leading forward slash. 
Change that to

`app.delete("/wordlist/:id"...`
And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your form to use the Delete verb

```
<form action="/wordlist/<%= word._id %>" method="DELETE">
  <button>
    Delete this word
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the form tag in HTML5 only allows GET and POST methods. Instead, you have to use a package such as method-override (which I am using) to send a DELETE request. When I made the change you suggested, it was sent as a GET request, even though I specified DELETE. So thanks, but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Relevant link:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms

Comment: Oh didn't realise this

Comment: Try change `app.delete` to `app.post` and see if it works